# Create vhost in wamp server

Tags: wamp

httpd.conf:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/"
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/error-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin shop@angels
    ServerName shop.angels
    ServerAlias www.shop.angels
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\magento"
    ErrorLog "logs/ag-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/ag-error-access.log" common
    <Directory /wamp/www/magento>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

file host:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       shop.angels
```

but when i visit shop.angels,  it redirect to localhost/magento (default url), what is the error?

Comment: Did you restart apache?

Answer (score 0):

It all look pretty good but you could try changing these few lines

From

```
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\magento"
```

To

```
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/magento"
```

From

```
<Directory /wamp/www/magento>
```

To

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/magento">
```

This next bit is just to remove the possibility of you getting IPV4/IPV6 ipaddress issues later

From

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

To

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
```

Or if you are using Apache V2.4.x change

From

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

To

```
Require local
```

You dont mention what version of WAMPServer or Apache you are using, if this last change causes an Apache error i.e. the `::1` ip address, then you are using an apache that does not yet understand IPV6, so you can leave off the `::1` address.

Answer (score 0):

If you have correctly configurated vhost, then delete folder **var/cache** and then F5

my httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/sgtest"
     ServerName sgtest.local.cz
     <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/sgtest">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
        Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```